# Selecionar uma opção que só é possível através do clique do mouse com vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou tentando desenvolver um *script* com vba, no **excel**, para facilitar uma rotina que temos no trabalho, que insere cerca de 9 mil dados no sistema interno. Atualmente fazemos manualmente a inserção desses dados. Esses dados nunca serão iguais, pois são obtidos após várias verificações de documentos.

Como esse sistema é uma página, que acessamos pelo *browser*, estou utilizando o `Application.SendKeys` para poder manipulá-lo. 
Ele possui dois *logins*. O primeiro é tranquilo de fazer e após fazê-lo, ele nos mostra uma seleção de sistemas (conforme a imagem abaixo)

[image: imagem]

Para acessar o segundo *login*, temos que selecionar o "PESSOAL". Mas só é possível selecioná-lo utilizando dois cliques do mouse. Apertar TAB e utilizar as setas até chegar na opção que preciso e depois apertar ENTER não resolve.

Seria possível fazer esse clique com o VBA? Já vi que tem algo como `.click`, mas não tenho ideia de como faria isso.

O código para gerar o quadro da imagem, está abaixo:

```
<!-- QUADRO DE SELECIONAR O SISTEMA-->
<span id="pnlUsuarioSistema_span" style = "position:absolute;top:210px;left:258px;height:197px;width:321px;background-color:F2F4F2;border-color:004080;border-style:Solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Verdana;font-size:11;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;">
<label name="lblTexto" id="lblTexto" style = "background-color:F2F4F2;color:004080;font-family:Verdana;font-size:12;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;height:21px;left:15px;position:absolute;top:15px;width:303px;">Selecione o sistema que deseja ingressar:</label>
<select  name="usrSysList" id="usrSysList" size="2" originalClass="DBList" style = "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;height:141px;left:17px;position:absolute;top:36px;width:285px;" ondblclick="openNewSession()">
<option value="http://(...)MAV">MAV</option>
<option value="http://(...)ORCOM">ORCOM</option>
<option value="http://(...)PESSOAL">PESSOAL</option>
</select>
</span>
<!-- FIM QUADRO -->
```

Comment: Eu não entendi os detalhes do problema. O sistema no nevagador é desenvolvido por vocês mesmos? Esse VBA está executando em qual ferramenta? Seria no Excel, por exemplo? Outra coisa (mais uma dica mesmo): vc já considerou utilizar o [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/)? Talvez seja muito mais simples do que tentar construir algo em VBA.

Comment: @LuizVieira estou escrevendo o _script_ no Excel. Esse sistema é bem antigo, mas não foi desenvolvido por nós. Não conhecia o AutoHotKey. Por ele seria possível utilizar dados de outro software, como o de uma planilha do Excel?

Comment: Acredito que não. Ele serve essencialmente para automatizar tarefas manuais (como o que eu entendi que vc queria fazer). Vc tem dados que *precisa* utilizar/manipular no Excel? Isso não está na pergunta. De todas as formas, eu desconheço se o VBA consegue fazer o que você quer nativamente, mas acredito que não. Entretanto, talvez seja possível reproduzir o que o AutoHotkey faz importando as APIs nativas do Windows. Dê uma olhada na função [`SendInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270.aspx).

Comment: Alguns exemplos que usam essa função pra simular pressionamento de teclas: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/411552-sendinput-visual-basic-applications.html e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896658/sendinput-vb-basic-example; Um exemplo de Click (mas é em VB, não em VBA): http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?734167-Mouse-Move-and-Click-with-Windows-API-Function-SendInput

Comment: Obrigado, @LuizVieira. Com esses endereços que você passou, acho que vou conseguir escrever uma rotina, para o que eu preciso.

Comment: Se conseguir, poste vc mesmo uma resposta aqui. Quem sabe ajuda outra pessoa no futuro. :)

Answer (score 2):

Estive lendo os links, que o @LuizVieira disponibilizou e ajudou bastante, no entendimento do que eu precisava. Mas não foi possível fazer exatamente o que eu estava procurando, por falta de conhecimento meu.

Foi então que eu cheguei nesse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055297/powerpoint-or-excel-vba-capture-coordinates-of-mouse-click), que possui o código abaixo e ele, de uma forma diferente, fez o que eu precisava, mas não como eu gostaria. Mas o problema foi solucionado.

```
Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10

Private Sub SingleClick()
  SetCursorPos 100, 100 'x and y position
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Sub

Private Sub DoubleClick()
  'Double click as a quick series of two clicks
  SetCursorPos 100, 100 'x and y position
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Sub

Private Sub RightClick()
  'Right Click
  SetCursorPos 200, 200 'x and y position
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Sub
```